# VB compile error BC30519 - No accessible New can be called without a Narrowing conversion

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a small program in VB which is to be operated from the command line.

It takes command line arguments for input and output files and converts them to strings.

I have a compile error on the file reading code and am having trouble finding a similar example in previously asked questions.

Here is the code.

```
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.
        FileIO.TextFieldParser(compmapfile)

        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(" ")
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
            For Each currentField In currentRow
                ReDim Preserve tempmap(i)
                tempmap(i) = currentfield
                i = i + 1
            Next
        End While
    End Using
```

compmapfile is a string containing the path to a text file (c:......file.txt).

If the actual path is enclosed in the brackets this code compiles fine, but otherwise I get the BC30519: Overload resolution failed error.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I would assume that compmapfile is not defined as a string then

Comment: It is as far as I know:

        `Dim compmapfile As String`
        `compmapfile = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(2)`

Comment: Well then the error doesn't make much sense - it compiles fine for me

Comment: I also find the same code complies fine in a separate file on it's own.

Here is the full error text:
`error BC30519: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
    'Public Sub New(reader As System.IO.TextReader)': Argument matching parameter 'reader' narrows from 'Object' to 'System.IO.TextReader'.
    'Public Sub New(stream As System.IO.Stream)': Argument matching parameter 'stream' narrows from 'Object' to 'System.IO.Stream'.
    'Public Sub New(path As String)': Argument matching parameter 'path' narrows from 'Object' to 'String'`

Comment: Can you post the full code containing all your variable declarations (edit your question to do this)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the code was being run in a different sub from the declaration, and I wasn't explicit when passing the compmapfile argument to the subroutine.

So I changed
    Sub HPcompmap(compmapfile)

to

```
Sub HPcompmap(compmapfile As String)
```

And the code compiled correctly.